# Why does my 7zip command now get a "Cannot find archive name" error

Tags: powershell, github-actions, 7zip, windows-server-2022

Without problems I've been using the following 7zip command on Appveyor CI in a .bat file using 7zip 21.07 running on Windows Server 2019, and also with earlier Windows Server & 7z versions:

```
7z -owin-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel e win-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel.zip
```

The identical command in a Powershell script on GitHub Actions CI using 7zip 22.01 running on Windows Server 2022 gets this error:

```
7-Zip 22.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2022 Igor Pavlov : 2022-07-15
Command Line Error:

Cannot find archive name
```

I've tried running it from cmd.exe

```
cmd.exe /C 7z -owin-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel e win-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel.zip
```

and also tried putting the command before the switch

```
7z e win-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel.zip -owin-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel
```

but I still get the error. `win-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel.zip` is present in the current directory and has the expected size.

EDIT: For the sake of completeness I should say that the name is taken from an environment variable. The actual command has `$env:OPENCL_SDK_NAME` instead of `win-oclcpuexp-2021.12.9.0.24_rel`.  In the .bat file the reference was, of course, `%OPENCL_SDK_NAME%`. I have verified that the variable has the expected value.

Why did this command stop working?

Comment: You don't need to call on cmd.exe since PowerShell is a Shell that can run utilities. It's probably the path, so if you're working directory isn't the same path where the .zip resides, you will get that error. You can also use `Expand-Archive` in PowerShell as well

Comment: A tool like Process Monitor can show you the actual parameters used to initialize 7z process. That should give you more hints on what's wrong.

Comment: @Abraham Zinala the WD is definitely where the .zip is. In any case I'm near certain the message indicates it can't find the archive name on the command line rather than it can't find the archive. I know PowerShell can run utilities. Since this previously worked in a .bat script I thought I'd give `cmd.exe /C` it a try.

Comment: @Lex Li, Is it possible to run process Monitor non-interactively and with output going to stdout? As this is happening on the CI server I can't use an interactive app. Anyway I'm going to try to reproduce the problem on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem on my local Windows box so with the help of ProcessMonitor, thanks [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li), I figured out what was happening. It's all down to Powershell handling of variable expansion. As a relative newbie to PS and long time bash/sh user I find PS's behavior surprising.

The actual command I had was

```
7z -o$env:OPENCL_SDK_NAME e $env:OPENCL_SDK_NAME.zip
```

I also had a preceding `curl` command using the same env. var. Because this worked it helped mask the issue.

```
curl.exe -s -S -L -O $env:OPENCL_SDK_HOME/$env:OPENCL_SDK_NAME.zip
```

So what is it? There are actually 2 problems:

1. With `-o$env:FOO` the variable is not expanded so the application sees exactly `-o$env:FOO`.
2. When seeing `$env:FOO.zip` PS substitutes an empty string, hence the `Cannot find archive name` error. I would never have spotted this without ProcessMonitor as the similar expansion in the`curl` command was working. It turns out that PS *does* expand the variable in the case of `foo/$env:FOO.zip`. Utterly bizarre.

My fix is to add quotes around the variables. For safety I added them to the `curl` command as well. I don't know if there are other better ways of fixing this.

```
curl.exe -s -S -L -O "$env:OPENCL_SDK_HOME/$env:OPENCL_SDK_NAME.zip"
7z -o"$env:OPENCL_SDK_NAME" e "$env:OPENCL_SDK_NAME.zip"
```